# Postgresql count(*) very slow on big table

Tags: count, postgresql-9.3

```
SELECT
T . ID,
T . DATE,
T . TIME,
T .i_want,
T .i_want_date,
T .i_want_date_to,
T . ACTION,
T .country,
T .url,
T .user_agent,
(
    SELECT
        client. NAME
    FROM
        client client
    WHERE
        client. ID = T .client_id
) AS client_name,
(
    SELECT
        segment. NAME
    FROM
        segment segment
    WHERE
        segment. ID = T .segment_id
) AS segment_name
   FROM
analytics_visitors T 
   WHERE
(1 = 1)
   AND (T .site_id = 3)
```

And when i apply count on it for pagination purpose like

```
SELECT "count"(*) FROM analytics_visitors T WHERE (1 = 1) AND (T .site_id = 3)
```

it is too much slow, please give any solution how can i optimize it or even change my main query , my postgresql is version 9.3 ,it contains 20000000+ rows and it is indexed also.

Comment: This might be helpful - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

Comment: Define "slow" and show `EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, BUFFERS, ANALYZE) SELECT ...` for your query.

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: please tell me how can analyze my table automatically i.e when new data inserted in it, then i want the updated statistics of my table